# Download Cloudinary data from EC2

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-ec2, cloudinary

I use PHP Symfony for my backend. I need to download cloudinary data into my EC2 instance using the cloudinary url of a single file or folder. For that, i wanted to create a PHP script to do that.

I use cloudinary_php package (https://packagist.org/packages/cloudinary/cloudinary_php). I use the upload functionality to store my data,  but it doesn't seem to have a download method.

I wanted to know if this is possible, with cloudinary_php or with another pachage ? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know anything about Cloudinary, but if you have a URL can't you just fetch from it directly? If they are 404'ing, it might be because of [this](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016480179-PDF-or-ZIP-files-appearing-in-Media-Library-but-download-URLs-return-an-error-).

Answer (score 1):

In your Symfony's project root folder, you should have the file composer.json. Then add following entry that looks like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "cloudinary/cloudinary_php": "^2"
    }
}
```

Then make sure to install the dependencies. Follow this [composer doc](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-dependencies). After that, you can now then plug in your API key and Secret then instantiate a Cloudinary object:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Cloudinary\Configuration\Configuration;
use Cloudinary\Api\Upload\UploadApi;

// configure globally via a JSON object
Configuration::instance([
  'cloud' => [
    'cloud_name' => 'your-cloud-name-here', 
    'api_key' => 'xxxxxxxx', 
    'api_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxx'
  ],  
  'url' => [
    'secure' => true
  ]
]);


//Instanstiate and generate an archive
$cloudinary = (new UploadApi());
$response = $cloudinary->createZip([
    'tags' => 'jeep',   // Change this base on your use case
    'resource_type' => 'image'  // Change this base on your use case
]);

//Check the response object
print_r($response);
//Make your own implementation here to download the archive.
```

The response object above should have the `secure_url` key where you can directly download the generated archive link. Visit the [documentation here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#create_zip_syntax) for more info. There are also lots of [optional parameters](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#generate_archive_optional_parameters) you can pass and you should choose what works best for you. You should also consider Symfony's security [best practices](https://symfony.com/doc/5.3/configuration/secrets.html) when referencing sensitive information. For general Cloudinary PHP SDK integration, visit [this](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_integration).